# Changing logback.xml file in Jenkins without rebuilding code

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, logback, devops

I have configured logback.xml to change log level during build time using "scan" property. Using this I can change log level without rebuilding the code. I can change log level by updating logback.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- 
For more configuration information and examples see
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html-->
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
<!--<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />-->
<!-- Debugging appender (duplicates the normal log, PLUS any debug messages) -->
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %level{5} %c{3} --- %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<!---->

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./log/elk-file.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <!--cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart-->
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>./log/elk-file_%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %level{5} %c{3} - %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<!-- Our logger writes to file, console and sends the data to Logstash -->
<logger name="ro.fortsoft.elk.testdata" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STASH"/>
</logger>

<logger level="INFO" name="rollingFileLogger">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>        


<!-- ROOT logger setup -->
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
```

How can I do this in Jenkins, i-e change logback.xml and change log level without rebuilding the code.